# Django South Migrations Failure on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-south, amazon-rds

I have a Python/Django server deployed successfully to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However after a successful deploy I've created some new South migrations. When I re-deploy to elastic beanstalk, everything pushes up but the south migrations don't apply and I get database errors on the new fields.

I tried to redeploy via git aws.push and eb update to the server. But neither command seems to update RDS. There is no error when I re-deploy, so it has me pretty confused.

**.config file:**

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_createadmin:
    command: "scripts/createadmin.py"
    leader_only: true
  03_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  04_migrate_expedition_granted:
    command: "python manage.py migrate users --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: Are you using the same database on both? I had a similar issue wit Postgres 9.3 in my development environment and 9.1 in production that caused some missing info when I did South migrations.

Comment: Yes. Running Mysql 5.5 on my local machine and on AWS RDS.

Comment: I don't think syncdb is even running because I am getting this error ... "Table 'ebdb.django_site' doesn't exist"

Comment: Did you run the syncdb first before running South "migrate"?  I'm not sure though.  My issue was due to different DB versions that caused unexpected issues.

Comment: After hours of trying to figure out what was wrong, it turned out to be the .config was in the gitignore and not being deployed the server..... sigh. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Could you close this question? I was found it like a question and you resolved your problem, so.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .config file is not inside the git .gitignore file.